# How to verify if the content of a specific table field is univocal?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I am not very into database and I have the following problem: I have a table with many many records and I have to verify if in this table some records have the same value for a specific field (so I have to check if a specific field is not univocal)

So for example I have a table named **MaliciousCodeAlertDocument** and I want verify if the **Title** field is an univocal field or not.

What can I do to it? I am thinking that maybe I can use **count** and **group by** but I have many doubt about how do it in practice.

Can you help me?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server and not mysql, you can do it with count and group by:

```
SELECT Title, COUNT(1) AS TitleCount
FROM MaliciousCodeAlertDocument
GROUP BY Title
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

This will only return records where the Title field is repeated, so if it returns no records, the field is "univocal".